# Collapsing window intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

I have a data base like the following:

```sql
select * from (
  values ('A', 1, 2), ('A', 2, 3), ('A', 3, 4),
         ('B', 4, 5), ('B', 5, 6), ('A', 6, 7),
         ('C', 7, 8), ('C', 8, 9)
) example_table("state", "start", "end")

-- example table: 
-- state start stop
--     A    t1   t2
--     A    t2   t3
--     A    t3   t4
--     B    t4   t5
--     B    t5   t6
--     A    t6   t7
--     C    t7   t8
--     C    t8   t9
```

I want to collapse the intervals by `state` while also respecting intervening state switches:

```
state start stop
    A    t1   t4
    B    t4   t6
    A    t6   t7
    C    t7   t9
```

Simply using `group by state` won't work since there are multiple rows in the output for a given `state`.

It seems like a use case for [window functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html), but I'm not sure by what to partition the rows.

I'd like to create a `group_id` like follows as an intermediate step:

```
group state start stop
    1     A    t1   t2
    1     A    t2   t3
    1     A    t3   t4
    2     B    t4   t5
    2     B    t5   t6
    3     A    t6   t7
    4     C    t7   t8
    4     C    t8   t9
```

I could then group by `group` and select `min(start)` and `max(stop)`, but I don't know how to create this variable (efficiently). In R I would use the `rle` function to do so, but I don't know any Presto equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer has been updated to reflect the following successful answer

```sql
with example_table("state", "start", "end") as (
  values ('A', 1, 2), ('A', 2, 3), ('A', 3, 4),
         ('B', 4, 5), ('B', 5, 6), ('A', 6, 7),
         ('C', 7, 8), ('C', 8, 9)
), table_with_lags as (
  -- detect state changes by observing the lagged value
  select *, lag(state) over(order by start) as lag_state,
  -- need to track the final value since it may be lost below
  last_value("end") over(order by start rows between 
                         0 preceding and unbounded following)
  as end_period
  from example_table
)
select state, start, 
       -- force-re-establish the start(+1) = end(0) link;
       --   at the end of the period, override this with the
       --   final observed value instead of null
       lead(start, 1, end_period) over(order by start) as "end"
from table_with_lags
-- lag_state will be null for the first row
where state <> lag_state or lag_state is null
order by start
```

With output:

```
state start stop
    A     1    4
    B     4    6
    A     6    7
    C     7    9
```

The `rows between 0 preceding and unbounded following` bit is a bit verbose, so you could also flip the logic and do:

```sql
table_with_leads as (
  select state, start, "end", 
         lead(state) over(order by start) as lead_state,
         first_value(start) over(order by start) as start_period
  from example_table
)
select state, lag("end", 1, start_period) over(order by start) as start, "end"
from table_with_lags
where state <> lead_state or lead_state is null
order by start
```

---

#### original answer

The following works, but is not performant at scale (even on a 10% subsample of the data, I get an "exceeded local memory limit" error):

```sql
with switches as (
  -- coalesce since the first row will be NULL, need it false
  select *, coalesce(state <> lag(state) over(order by start), false) switched
  from (
    values ('A', 1, 2), ('A', 2, 3), ('A', 3, 4),
           ('B', 4, 5), ('B', 5, 6), ('A', 6, 7),
           ('C', 7, 8), ('C', 8, 9)
  ) example_table("state", "start", "stop")
), groups as (
  -- create the group ID as the accumulation of the state switches
  --   since only one state switch can happen per group
  select *, sum(cast(switched as bigint)) over (order by start) group_id
  from switches
)
select min(state) state, min(start) start, max(stop) stop
from groups group by group_id order by start;

-- state start stop
--     A     1    4
--     B     4    6
--     A     6    7
--     C     7    9
```

I *have* currently found success by temporarily storing `groups` as a table, then separately `select`ing from `groups`, which appears to get around the RAM issue (somewhat surprisingly to me). This hardly seems ideal, but as it gets the job done, I'm content to stick with this for now.